# If-else-then with xml in shell

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have these variables:

```
a=`echo "$(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency['code="\"$codea\""']/amount/text()' rates.xml)"`
b=`echo "$(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency['code="\"$codeb\""']/amount/text()' rates.xml)"`
```

let's say a =10000
          b=1

How do i write if statement if i want to verify if variable a is bigger than variable b?

Comment: Check your useless use of echo.

Answer (score 2):

The classic way:

```
if [ $a -gt $b ]
then
    something here ...
else
    something different ...
fi
```

a variation:

```
if [[ $a -gt $b ]]
```

Or the aritmetic expansion can be used

```
if (( a > b )); then whatever; else anything; fi
```